# Cross Domain AJAX call not working in IE11

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, internet-explorer-11

I am trying a make a cross domain AJAX call. It works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11. IE11 seems to drop the AJAX call. IE11 Developer Tools Network reveals that a request is not even made to the **url**. Here is snippet of code I have.

```
$(function() {
  var url = "https://example.com?abc=xyz";
  $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    contentType : "text/plain",
    url : url + "&callback=?",
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    xhrFields : {
        withCredentials : false
    },
    headers : {},
    success : function() {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error : function() {
        console.log("error");
    },
    complete : function() {
        console.log("complete");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    cache: false,
```

or before ajax call

```
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

   $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
```